# Getting image from array

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I was trying to create a slider to show my projects and created an array to get info to insert it into html. But i could not get the images to change and all the text and heading is changing. I tried changing the source by some help from other answeres but i could not do it. This is what the array looks like :

```
var Projects = [

    {
      "heading" : "Online Library website",
      "img" :      "./project3.png",
      "text"  : ` TEXT`
    },

     {
        "heading"  : "Food ordering website",
        "img"  :  "./project4.png",  
        "text"     : ` TEXT `
    },

    {
      "heading"  : "Random Quotes",
      "img"  :   "./project1.png",
      "text"    : ` TEXT`
  }
  ]
```

Javascript code :

```
     let nxtarrow = document.getElementById('next-arrow');
  let prevarrow = document.getElementById('prev-arrow');


  let heading = document.getElementById('title');
  let text = document.getElementById('text');
  let img = document.getElementById('Projectimg');
  console.log(img.src);

  var currentHead = 0;

  nxtarrow.onclick = function(){

    if(currentHead == (Projects.length -1)){
       currentHead = 0;
    }
    else{
      currentHead++;
    }

    var title = Projects[currentHead].heading;
    var para = Projects[currentHead].text;
    var imgsrc = Projects[currentHead].img;
    heading.innerHTML = title;
    text.innerHTML = para;
    imgsrc.src = imgsrc;

    let ss = $('#Projectimg').attr('src', Projects.img)
    console.log(ss);
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the path is correct? Show your folder structure

Comment: "D:\HTML\All Projects\Portfolio project\project1.png"  here is the path to the image.

Comment: And where is your `html` file?

Comment: It is in the Portfolio project folder.

Comment: Hey thanks for replying i found the issue.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Hey sorry i could not check your reply. There was a mistake in JS code (4th line from end) i used imgsrc instead of img.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have saved images in the Project folder and that all the URLs are correct.

```
 -> Images Folder
      .project1.png
      .project2.png
```

Add the correct URL in the Projects Array:

```
   var Projects = [

{
  "heading" : "Online Library website",
  "img" :      "./project3.png",
  "text"  : ` TEXT`
},

 {
    "heading"  : "Food ordering website",
    "img"  :  "./project4.png",  
    "text"     : ` TEXT `
},

{
  "heading"  : "Random Quotes",
  "img"  :   "./project1.png",
  "text"    : ` TEXT`
  }
  ]

-->Javascript Code
     //some code
```

Comment: Hey thanks for replying i found the issue.